# How to select option from a combobox in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to put value in a combo-box using python selenium. As we enter text it gives different possible values in dropdown. How to select the first value on the drop down? As soon as I try to click on it, it removes the text and makes it blank.

[image]
[image]

So, for example, I am sending the text `Stockholms kommun, Stockholms län` in the `combobox` by:

```
text = Stockholms kommun, Stockholms län
inputcity = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="price-calculator-address"]')
inputcity.send_keys(text)
```

However, I am not able to click (as shown in image-2) on the dropdown which appears as I enter the text.

Link of website: https://www.hemnet.se/annonsera-bostad#priskalkylatorn

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick is to enter the text and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice. Basically imitate the manual actions if it was to be done via human.

Try the below working code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.hemnet.se/annonsera-bostad#priskalkylatorn")
driver.maximize_window()
# below line will accept cookies
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Jag samtycker']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='price-calculator-address']").send_keys("Stockholms kommun, Stockholms län")
time.sleep(3)
# below line will press TAB key 2 times
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='price-calculator-address']").send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB)
```

**Result:**
[image]